# TCP connect error "No buffer space available"

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection

I got this error when I was testing a home-made distributed key-value store on very large scale (2048 machines), it works fine on 1024 machines. The communication pattern is n:n,which means each machine send lots of requests to every one else.
I used C TCP socket to implement it, SO_REUSEADDR to recycle those sockets. 
Can any one give me some tips about the possibilities that can cause this error? The code is complex, It's hard to simplify it and post here without losing necessary logic. So I just want to know all the possible causes to start to debug.

BTW I changed settings as:
echo 8000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

echo 8000 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn #limit of listen queue, default is 128

echo 8000 > /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog

echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout

echo "10000   65000" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

I did this is just for enable maximum number of connections.

Thanks,
-Tony

Comment: Too many open descriptors could cause this error, also MTU misconfigurations and a number of other conditions, I imagine. Impossible to tell for sure without some minimal code example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The error was not "too many open file descriptors" which I met before. I also have these settings: echo 8000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max;;
echo 8000 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn;; 
echo 8000 > /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog;;
echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout;;
echo "10000   65000" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as your “No buffer space available” error. That echo patch you did is considered as temporary settings.

After you change the temporary settings using echo (as described above), you will need to restart the network, which cleared the "no buffer space available" error.

You will need to add the permanent settings by adding the line at the end of /etc/sysctl.conf file:

somaxconn = 8000

See here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/linux-kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

Hope it helps.

Robert

http://NetworkCities.com